# How to track the changes in a cell value by comparing to the original template in MS Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

Let's say I have original excel sheet/templete which looks like,

```
ID    | Value
-------------------------
1     | abcd
2     | wxyz
3     | lmno
```

Now, I download daily excel reports which, if all goes well, should look identical to the original template shown above. Meaning all 'Value' for corresponding 'Id' should remain unchanged. Once in a while a 'Value' may change for an 'ID'. I'd like to track this changed 'Value'. I have the original excel file (as shown above) to compare (the newly downloaded) report against. How to do it?

It really doesn't matter what results/output I expect as long as they are noticeable. It'll work for me if the solution makes the row bold of the changed value or even better write down 'ID' of the changed 'Value' in next sheet.

Thanks.
PS. 'ID' column is unique.

Comment: Does your sheet contains these columns as A and B columns, i.e. the first 2 columns?

Comment: ID column isn't sorted (& it's alphanumeric). Report is a different workbook. These aren't A & B columns in real. In reality, ID column is 'Q' and Value column is 'A'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a helper column in the Sheet you want to test.
Say your source range is A2:B4 in Sheet1, and the (target) range you want to test is A2:B4 in Sheet2, then

1. Use the following formula in Sheet2!C2

   =IF(VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!$A$2:$C$4)<>B2,"WARNING","")
2. Set a filter in columns A:C of Sheet2.
3. Filter "WARNING".

You can then copy those changed cases somewhere else, or take other various actions.

Comment: You have saved some man hours!!
In above vlookup formula though, third argument is needed.